# Variable declaration and definition mismatch

Tags: c, c89

I am using a C89 compiler (embedded systems).

I ran into some C code where one translation unit defines a variable as `bool varName;`, where `bool` is a `typedef` of `unsigned char`.  Another translation unit forward declares the variable as follows: `extern char varName;`.

This is obviously a type mismatch, and is an error.  My question is, what exact rule does this violate?  My knee-jerk reaction was that it is an ODR violation, but there is a single definition so I'm not confident that this is an ODR violation.

Comment: Which of these languages are you interested in? You are speaking of C, but you list three C++ tags.

Comment: I don't think it's valid C++, as `bool` is a type on its own.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: Without a clear idea of which language and version you're discussing, this is difficult to answer correctly

Comment: Good question but I think you are asking about C not C++

Comment: Since the definitions cross translation units, the question boils down, if the ABI treats both types the same. This is obviously the case here, so this shouldn't be a problem. I would even say, that this question is out of scope for the C standard

Comment: I have updated the tags to reference only C and C89.  My code is specifically being compiled by a C89 compiler.

Comment: `char varName;` is a definition, not just a declaration.

Comment: @interjay Thanks for pointing that out.  I added the `extern` keyword there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[6.2.7p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7p2)

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have
>   compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The [C89 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html) has the same paragraph.

Declarations referfing to the same object is further explained in the paragraph on linkage:

> An identifier declared in different scopes or in the same scope more
>   than once can be made to refer to the same object or function by a
>   process called linkage . There are three kinds of linkage: external,
>   internal, and none.
>
> In the set of translation units and libraries that constitutes an
>   entire program, each instance of a particular identifier with external
>   linkage denotes the same object or function. Within one translation
>   unit, each instance of an identifier with internal linkage denotes the
>   same object or function. Identifiers with no linkage denote unique
>   entities.

Compatible types essentially means identical types, with some minor caveats (e.g., `extern int foo[];` is compatible with `extern int foo[3];`).